Modifying Sublime Build so that it can modify/restart Docker services
I am working on a code base that involves Docker. I start Docker by running docker compose up. I make changes to Python files. I enter the Docker container using docker exec command with the relevant parameters. I then run python [my file name] to run the actual Python code.
The problem is that, every time I make a change in the Python file, I have to go through command line to restart the Docker container, and then to enter the Docker container, and then to run the Python code.
I am wondering if I can modify my .sublime-build file to automate this process?
The manual process I am going through is so annoying that I resorted to making changes to the Python files in Docker Desktop, just because their GUI is so easy that it makes it easier to restart (at least in my opinion, compared to using the Terminal).
Thanks for your suggestions on improving my workflow!
I've tried using ChatGPT for help, and they mention that I might have to modify my docker-compose.yml file. ChatGPT says if I modify my .yml file, then I do not need to rebuild Docker every time I make changes. Instead, the changes will immediately be reflected inside my container.
The yaml code that ChatGPT suggested is shown below:
version: '3.8'
services:
  platform-ingest:
    image: your_image_name
    volumes:
      - ./path/to/local/code:/path/inside/container


You should modify your workflow to not need the docker exec step; just docker run the container should start the Python application.  Then docker compose build; docker compose up -d will restart the container with the new code, without manual intervention.  I would not add volumes: that overwrite the application code with content from the host.

"You should modify your workflow to not need the docker exec step"
How would I do this?

What is the Dockerfile's current CMD?  Can you change that to be the thing you're running in the docker exec command?
